# Java iterator: hasNext() returns true but next() is null?

Tags: java, iterator

In the `following code`, `tupleIterator.hasNext()` returns `true` but `tupleIterator.next()` is `null`.

```
if (this.tupleIterator != null) {
    if (this.tupleIterator.hasNext()) {
        tuple = this.tupleIterator.next();
        return tuple;
    }
}
```

`this.tupleIterator` was derived by calling `iterator()` method on `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have added `null` in your arraylist so if you do not want null values in the lust you can do this by either checking before adding value to the list or you can extend Arraylist class
and override

```
boolean add(E e)
void add (int index, E e)
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems your Interator has values, but they were inserted as `null`. Without the code before this part is hard to say.